# How to addClass Url Parmeter

Tags: jquery

It doesn't work.
help.

example url: .../list.html?cate_no=800

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.urlParam = function(name){
            var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            if (results==null) {
               return null;
            }
            return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
        }
        var id = $.urlParam('cate_no');
        $(id).addClass("active");
});
```

html

```
<li><a id="800" href="/product/list_journal.html?cate_no=800">ex</a></li>
<li><a id="700" href="/product/list_journal.html?cate_no=700">ex</a></li>
```

I would like to addClass active with the parameter value of the current address window.
It doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is here `var id = $.urlParam('cate_no');`, this would return something like `800` so when you do `$(id)` it would be `$(800)` but it should be `$(#800)` so change it to `$("#"+id)`. Also you might wanner read https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2943218

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [URL searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)
2. To make your life easier do not have anything that is going to be used in a JavaScript selector start with a number or contain special characters

```js
$(function() {
  const url = new URL("https://www.exaplen.com/product/list_journal.html?cate_no=c700");  // new URL(location.href); 
  const id = url.searchParams.get("cate_no");
  $(`#${id}`).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none;}
a.active { text-decoration:underline; color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a id="c800" href="/product/list_journal.html?cate_no=c800">ex</a></li>
<li><a id="c700" href="/product/list_journal.html?cate_no=c700">ex</a></li>
```

If possible just use hash - no script needed at all:

```css
a {
    background-color: #00A087;
}
a:target {
   background-color: #F37736;
}
```

```html
<li><a id="c800" href="#c800">Click one of these</a></li>
<li><a id="c700" href="#c700">Click one of these</li>
```